# starting new line at n in html / JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my rss feeds which display to start a new line on the description at n characters so it could just sit at the side of a page and not go far to the middle. I'm wondering if this is possible?
I don't have static html data as the descriptions are returned as JSON. I think this means I need to do it in JS where I can say in a hbs helper or something "at n start new line" but I'm not sure how to do that.
fiddle showing my html currently (there is no json or hbs attached so it looks messy sorry) http://jsfiddle.net/872e3/1/

here's the kind of logic i'm thinking about (it will be written as my thinking not as legitimate code)

```
handlebars.registerHelper("length", function(result) {
if (character.current == 64) {
starnewline
}
else continue
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean with "it could just sit at the side of a page and not go to far to the middle"? As I understood the question, you just want <br />'s at character n, but this confused me

Comment: Yeah I mean if you imagine for example this site http://www.bbc.co.uk/news it has all of its information in the middle and the left and right hand side are white space, I mean the oppasite of that, as if the feed were in the left part of the page and the descriptions would <br /> at n to stop it going into the middle

Comment: Why don't you just set the width of the containing <div> element to say 33% so it won't overflow?

Comment: @DavingtonIII what Lubos Menus suggested should work for what you want. You just restrict the width of your container (.rssContainer or .tab or .item), depends on your desires.

Comment: Haha yeah, I guess I was over thinking it :D Thanks ^^ I've done that and it works how I want <3

Comment: @DavingtonIII happens to the best :p